# Issues with image field (PRO) in Laravel BackPack

Tags: laravel-backpack

I have this crud controller :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Requests\HotelRequest;
use Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\CrudController;
use Backpack\CRUD\app\Library\CrudPanel\CrudPanelFacade as CRUD;

/**
 * Class HotelCrudController
 * @package App\Http\Controllers\Admin
 * @property-read \Backpack\CRUD\app\Library\CrudPanel\CrudPanel $crud
 */
class HotelCrudController extends CrudController
{
    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\ListOperation;
    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\CreateOperation;
    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\UpdateOperation;
    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\DeleteOperation;
    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\ShowOperation;

    /**
     * Configure the CrudPanel object. Apply settings to all operations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function setup()
    {
        CRUD::setModel(\App\Models\Hotel::class);
        CRUD::setRoute(config('backpack.base.route_prefix') . '/hotel');
        CRUD::setEntityNameStrings('hotel', 'hotels');
    }

    /**
     * Define what happens when the List operation is loaded.
     *
     * @see  https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/crud-operation-list-entries
     * @return void
     */
    protected function setupListOperation()
    {
        CRUD::addColumn([
            'name'         => 'company', // name of relationship method in the model
            'type'         => 'relationship',
            'label'        => 'Empresa', // Table column heading
        ]);
        CRUD::addColumn([
            'name'         => 'name', // name of relationship method in the model
            'label'        => 'Nombre', // Table column heading
        ]);
        /**
         * Columns can be defined using the fluent syntax:
         * - CRUD::column('price')->type('number');
         */
    }

    /**
     * Define what happens when the Create operation is loaded.
     *
     * @see https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/crud-operation-create
     * @return void
     */
    protected function setupCreateOperation()
    {
        CRUD::setValidation(HotelRequest::class);
        //CRUD::setFromDb(); // set fields from db columns.

        // section General information
        CRUD::field([
            'name'  => 'company',
            'label' => 'Compañía',
            'wrapper'   => [
                'class' => 'form-group col-md-10'
            ],
        ])->tab('Información general');

        CRUD::field([
            'name'  => 'enabled',
            'type'  => 'switch',
            'label' => 'Habilitado',
            'color'    => 'primary',
            'wrapper'   => [
                'class' => 'form-group col-md-2 text-center d-flex align-items-center pt-5'
            ],
            'tab' => 'Información general'
        ]);

        CRUD::field([
            'name'  => 'internalname',
            'type'  => 'text',
            'label' => 'Nombre interno',
            'tab' => 'Información general'
        ]);

        CRUD::field([
            'name'  => 'logo',
            'type'  => 'image',
            'label' => 'Logo',
            'wrapper' => [
                'class' => 'form-group col-md-3'
            ],
            'withFiles' => true,
            'tab' => 'Información general'
        ]);

        CRUD::field([
            'name'  => 'stickylogo',
            'type'  => 'image',
            'label' => 'Logo Sticky',
            'wrapper' => [
                'class' => 'form-group col-md-3'
            ],
            'withFiles' => true,
            'tab' => 'Información general'
        ]);

        CRUD::field([
            'name'  => 'name',
            'type'  => 'text',
            'label' => 'Título',
            'wrapper'   => [
                'class' => 'form-group col-md-6'
            ],
            'tab' => 'Información general'
        ]);

        CRUD::field([
            'name'  => 'slug',
            'type'  => 'slug',
            'target' => 'name',
            'label' => 'Slug',
            'wrapper'   => [
                'class' => 'form-group col-md-6'
            ],
            'attributes' => [
                'readonly' => 'readonly'
            ],
            'tab' => 'Información general'
        ]);

        CRUD::field([
            'name'  => 'email',
            'type'  => 'email',
            'label' => 'Correo electrónico',
            'prefix' => '<i class="la la-envelope"></i>',
            'wrapper'   => [
                'class' => 'form-group col-md-6'
            ],
            'tab' => 'Información general'
        ]);

        CRUD::field([
            'name'  => 'telephone',
            'type'  => 'phone',
            'label' => 'Teléfono',
            'wrapper'   => [
                'class' => 'form-group col-md-6'
            ],
            'config' => [
                'initialCountry' => 'es',
                'nationalMode' => true,
                'autoHideDialCode' => false
            ],
            'tab' => 'Información general'
        ]);
        
    }

    /**
     * Define what happens when the Update operation is loaded.
     *
     * @see https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/crud-operation-update
     * @return void
     */
    protected function setupUpdateOperation()
    {
        $this->setupCreateOperation();
    }
}
```

When save the form, even without any change, the photos path  are deleted from de DB

#### PHP VERSION:

PHP 8.3.4 (cli) (built: Mar 16 2024 08:40:08) (NTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.3.4, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v8.3.4, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
with Xdebug v3.3.1, Copyright (c) 2002-2023, by Derick Rethans

#### LARAVEL VERSION:

10.45.1.0

#### BACKPACK PACKAGE VERSIONS:

backpack/basset: 1.2.4
backpack/crud: 6.6.4
backpack/devtools: 3.0.4
backpack/editable-columns: 3.0.7
backpack/generators: v4.0.3
backpack/pagemanager: 3.3.0
backpack/permissionmanager: 7.2.0
backpack/pro: 2.1.7
backpack/theme-tabler: 1.2.3

Comment: Seems that the issue is related to the use of HasTranslations trait. If I remove the trait, the crud works fine

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have `logo` and `stickylogo` image fields in the `$translatable` array of your model.

Please remove and retry.